# Convert camera capture image like camscanner image flutter

Tags: flutter

I have implemented a app to capture image from camera and convert it to pdf and share that image.But I want to display camera captured image like on camscanner image using image processing, Can anyone suggest to dart library to do my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a suitable answer for my requirement. I have used "edge_detection 1.0.5" package for detect edges for capture image so then final output will same as camscanner output.

https://pub.dev/packages/edge_detection